# How to create a bijection between X and Y

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, problem-solving

Preamble

As we have seen $(0,1)\cup(1,2)$ is not a connected subset of $\mathbb R.$ However both (0,1) and (1,2) are connected, and further more, for each point in (0,1) ,(0,1) is the largest connected subset of $(0,1) \cup
(1,2)$ containing the point. Similarly,(1,2) is the largest connected subset of $(0,1)\cup(1,2)$ containing each of its points

The same “amount of of dis-connectivity” does not guarantee homeomorphism.

**Problem Statement**

Let $X=(0,1) \cup (1,2)$ with the relative topology inherited from the usual topology on R and let Y={a,b} with the discrete topology. Show that there is a 1-1 correspondence between the components of X and the components of Y,but X and Y are not homeomorphic

**What I know**

(0,1),(1,2) are intervals and infinite

In general if a$\ne$ b (a,b)~R

Y is discrete and finite.
No bijection between X and Y ,thus no Homeomorphism.

Components of X are (0,1),(1,2) with two end points per interval.

**Attempted proof**

0$\leftrightarrow$ {a}

1$\leftrightarrow$ {b}

It’s bijective.

This is probably wrong.

I could use the S-B theorem

Am l on the correct path?

Comment: Which part are you struggling with? Finding a bijection or proving a homeomorphism doesn't exist?

Comment: Well both. Let’s start with the bijection

Comment: If you eqipp an uncountable set with the disrete topology, it has uncountable many components. X has two components. So, there will be no bijection.

Comment: Y ={a,b} not Y=[a,b]. Typo. It could make a the difference. If not your answer explains I guess why it’s not a Homeomorphism.No bijection exists.

Comment: @user940347 There is a bijection lol, there just isn't a homeo.

Comment: @HomerSimpson What have you tried for proving a bijection exists?

Comment: @DonThousand Between what objects do you want bijections?! Between the set of components of X and the set of components of Y. Ok, but then it is no meaningful question to ask, if that is a homeomorphism because the sets between those mapping acts aren't topological spaces.

Comment: @user940347 That's the point of the question...

Comment: Between X components and Y components @DonThousand

Comment: So Conover screwed up in asking to show a bijection exists @user940347

Comment: I just edited it. @DonThousand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints: $X = (0, 1) \cup (1, 2)$ has two connected components and so you can find a $1$-$1$ correspondence (or bijection if you prefer) between the set of connected components of $X$ and any set with two elements. If you give any set $Y$ the discrete topology, then its connected components are the singleton sets $\{y\}$ for $y \in Y$. So if $Y = \{a, b\}$ (where $a\neq b$) is given the discrete topology it has two connected components: so its connected components can be put in $1$-$1$ correspondence with those of $X$. If $X$ and $Y$ were homeomorphic, they would have the same number of elements, but $X$ is infinite and $Y$ is finite.

Comment: I have this theorem  and thought of basing my argument after 
this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1283602/let-a-0-cup-1-2-cup-3-and-b-0-1-cup-2-cup-3-pro
**Theorem 3.7** 

Let X. & Y be topological spaces and let h:X$\mapsto$Y be a Homeomorphism of X onto Y. Then for each x$\in$X h($C_x$)=$C_{h(x)}$ and for each y$\in$ Y, $h^{-1}(C_y)$=$C_{h^{-1}(y)}$

Comment: Well done for finding a related MSE question, but that question is solving a harder problem, where the homeomorphism between two subspaces of $\Bbb{R}$ was required to extend to all of $\Bbb{R}$ (which turned out to be impossible). You don't have any constraint like that in this problem. Thanks for the green tick.

Comment: I eventually have to solve it.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your comment. Do you not understand the answer to the other question?

Comment: I can’t see how X is infinite. So Theorem 3.7 does not apply

Comment: You haven't given enough of "Theorem 3.7" for me to be able to comment (what does $C_x$ mean). To see $X$ is infinite, note that $1/n \in X$ for $n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots$. In fact all you need is that $X$ doesn't have exactly $2$ elements to see that it cannot be homeomorphic with the $2$-element space $Y$.

Comment: $C_x$=$\bigcup${K$\subset$ X,K connected,x$\in$ K}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130160/discussion-between-homer-simpson-and-rob-arthan).

Comment: So I can create a bijection between an infinite set an finite one  and that would solve it . I saw somewhere on MSE that generally $C_x$:$\longrightarrow$ f($C_x$) is one such mapping

Comment: You certainly can't create a bijection between an infinite set and a finite set. However you can create a bijection between $\{ (0, 1), (1, 2)\}$ (the connected components of $X$) and $\{\{a\}, \{b\}\}$ (the connected components of $Y$) and that is what is needed here.